# Problem between hyperlink and bibtex

Tags: bibtex, hyperref

I am using `hyperref` and BibTeX for my thesis. Everything works perfectly, when the citation is in the normal text i.e. the hyperlink is created to the bibliography and in the bibliography is done the hyper link to the section.

The problem begin when the reference is inside a  table, than in the figure the references number is properly generated, but in the bibliography appears the hyperlink as question mark instead the section where they are. Does anybody know what to do? I am using `\citep{}` for references.

My preamble:

```
\documentclass[arial,paper=a4]{book}


%************************************




\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage{nomencl}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{multirow}


%*************************Hyperlink***************************
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,colorlinks,backref,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,}



************************************************************************

\makeindex  



%**************************main body*************************

\begin{document}
\mainmatter 

\include{Introduction}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Bibliografia}

\end{document}
```

So looks my citation in the bibTex-file

```
@article{
Delbeke,
   Author = {Delbeke, D. and Coleman, R. E. and Guiberteau, M. J. and Brown, M. L. and Royal, H. D. and Siegel, B. A. and Townsend, D. W. and Berland, L. L. and Parker, J. A. and Hubner, K. and Stabin, M. G. and Zubal, G. and Kachelriess, M. and Cronin, V. and Holbrook, S.},
   Title = {Procedure guideline for tumor imaging with 18F-FDG PET/CT 1.0},
   Journal = {J Nucl Med},
   Volume = {47},
   Number = {5},
   Pages = {885-95},
    Year = {2006} }
```

#### The table

```
\begin{table*}[!ht]
\begin{center}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}p{3.5cm}ccccp{0.5cm}cccp{5.0cm}cccp{4cm}ccccc@{}}

\multicolumn{4}{c}{}\\ 

\textbf{Category} &&& \textbf{Factor} &&& \textbf{Explanation} &&&\textbf{ Reference} \\ 
\hline 

Patient Preparation &&& Fasting &&& \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\columnwidth} patient should be inform not to consume any food or drink, except water, between 4 to 6 hours before the FDG application \end{minipage}&&& \begin{minipage}[t]{0.1\columnwidth} \citep{Delbeke}
\citep{Boellaard, Boellaard-Netherland, Niederkohr, Krause, Waxman} \end{minipage}

\end{tabular*}
\end{center}
\end{table*}
```

---

[image: this is how the bibliography looks like and the table where I made the citation. All the citations in the table show the same problem. But the hyper link with the question mark works correct, I mean it goes to the correct page.]

This is how the bibliography looks like and the table where I made the citation. All the citations in the table show the same problem. But the hyper link with the question mark works correct, I mean it goes to the correct page.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I think tables and figures are float in latex. So instead of point sections , you can do backref=page .

Comment: Lovely it works!!!! so I did the follow in my preamble:  \usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,colorlinks,backref=page,linktocpage=true]{hyperref} and the problem was sovel. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @Flavia Sorry to bother you, but notice that if Aung's answer solved your problem, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 3):

I think tables and figures are float in latex. So instead of pointing sections , you can do backref=page as an option in hyperref.