# Head style and Contenst problem

Tags: formatting, chapters

I have two problems in one. I am writing my thesis using the package `fancyhdr`, and all my chapters look great. However I have to add some parts, which are not chapter but I would like to have the title as one.

The problem is my results do not look like as I expected.

All chapters look like:

[image]

So my idea is that no-chapter parts should look like:

[image]

But in real they look like:

[image]

and it gets worse, because my Contents looks awful.

[image]

I am using this preamble for the style of my heading.

```
\fancyhead{} \fancyhead[]{}

\fancyhead[RE]{\scriptsize\leftmark}

\fancyhead[LO]{\scriptsize\rightmark}\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\fancyfoot[]{}


And in the none-Chapter part I wrote


\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}

%\renewcommand\chaptername{\fontsize{50}{50}\selectfont\Large{Curriculum Vitae}}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont\Huge{Curriculum Vitae}}
```

I was trying too many solutions posted here, but none of those work for me. If I use `\chaptername` instead of `\thecapter` (which I know is the chapter number), the nice rectangle frame becomes into a line. if I use just `\chapter` no eve a line is generate and it is equivalent if I use `\chapter*{}`. I know the problem in the contents is because the `\fontsize` and the `\selectfont`, but those are the size which give me a properly size in the title.

Does anybody knows what to do? I would really appreciate any help. If you need to know my preamble it is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161817/problem-between-hyperlink-and-bibtex)

Regards,

Flavia

Comment: You seem to use the `fncychap` package that you don't mention. If that's the case, you could take the style used for numbered chapters as a basis and make an own style for unnumbered chapters. Alternatively, modify your re-definition of  `\thechapter` as follows : `\renewcommand\thechapter{{\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont\Huge{Curriculum Vitae}}\vphantom{0}}`, but I'm not sure there won't be unpredictable effects.

Comment: Please post a **complete** Minimal Working Example and not just fragments of code which leave people guessing what is used or what is relevant. This should be code which people can compile to reproduce the issue - not just the preamble - and it should contain *only* what is necessary to reproduce that issue - not the entire preamble.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `Lenny` chapter style from `fncychap` (this style is, in my opinion, a little ugly and perhaps you should reconsider using it). Redefining `\thechapter` to produce a title and its formatting is not the thing to do; `\thechapter` is only for the representation of the `chapter` counter; misusing it as you did in your example code will produce the undesired results you already experienced.

With the help of [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) and [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) I defined a command `\specialchapter` to produce a style for chapter headings like the one you want; the special chapter is produced using `\chapter*` and the ToC entry is added used `\addcontentsline`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\newcommand\specialchapter{%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\selectfont}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[inner ysep=0pt] (title)
      {\hspace*{15pt}\Huge\rmfamily##1\hspace*{15pt}};
    \draw[overlay] 
      ([xshift=10pt]title.south west) -- 
      (current page text area.west|-title.south west) --
      ++(0pt,40pt) --
      ++(\textwidth,0pt) --
      (current page text area.east|-title.south east) --
      ([xshift=-10pt]title.south east);
   \end{tikzpicture}% 
  }
}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Discussion and Perspectives}
{
\specialchapter
\chapter*{Curriculum Vitae}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Curriculum Vitae}
}
\chapter{Another regular chapter}

\end{document}
```

An image of the ToC:

[image]

A regular chapter:

[image]

The special chapter:

[image]

The next regular chapter:

[image]

Comment: @cfr Ah, yes. I'll fox it. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: Now I'm really intrigued... I'm certainly glad I'm not a chicken!

Comment: @cfr LOL! Sorry for the typo :) In the meantime, I "foxed" the code.

Comment: Yes you are right, I use fancycahp, sorry about the package.

Thanks for the code, I were never think something like that, however  it works partially. I mean it solve the first problem I posted, but now other parts of my thesis are damaged.

I am using \appendix an before the code they were looking  with the [Lenny] style, but now they are treated as  \specialchapter and look terrible.

Comment: @Flavia You need to keep the effect of `\specialchapter` local (the extra pair of braces in my example code). In your file `CV.tex` you then need: `{ \specialchapter \chapter*{Curriculum Vitae} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Curriculum Vitae} } And the content of the chapter goes here...` (again, notice the braces before `\specialchapter` and after the `\addcontententsline` command).

Comment: @ Gonzalo, Thanks I though something similar, like I am running out of time I decided to do to something inelegant but practice. I made my title as a figure.eps and I included the chapter in the Toc as \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Curriculum Vitae} Thanks for your time